# Generar array de paths desde un array recursivo PHP

Tags: php, array, rutas

me gustaría obtener un array con los distintos caminos (rutas) de los elementos de su interior, de manera que tras obtener sus padres y descendientes, pueda crear cadenas de textos con las rutas de los mismos, y separados por ";", de forma que de una estructura así:

```
array(1) {
  ["TLK-1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TLK-4"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["TLK-5"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["TLK-30"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["TLK-31_1"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      ["TLK-30_2"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["TLK-31"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["TLK-1_1"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["TLK-4_1"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["TLK-30_1"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Me gustaría que la salida fuera :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string() "TLK-1;TLK-4;TLK-5;TLK-30;"
  [1]=>
  string() "TLK-1;TLK-4;TLK-5;TLK-31_1;"
  [2]=>
  string() "TLK-1;TLK-4;TLK-30_2;"
  [3]=>
  string() "TLK-1;TLK-31;TLK-1_1;TLK-4_1;"
  [4]=>
  string() "TLK-1;TLK-31;TLK-1_1;TLK-30_1;"
}
```

He probado creando una función que recorre el array recursivamente, pero no logro obtener el resultado, por lo que le agradecería su ayuda:

```
function getStringDescendientes($escenario){
    $subEscenariosFinal = '';
    $arrayCpsFinal = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($escenario as $padre => $descendientes) {
        if(count($descendientes) > 0){
            foreach ($descendientes as $key => $subdescendientes) {
                $arrayCpsFinal[$key] = $padre.';'.$key.';';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $i = count($arrayCpsFinal);
        $arrayCpsFinal = array_merge($arrayCpsFinal, getStringDescendientes($descendientes));
    }
    return $arrayCpsFinal;
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para "*simplificar*" la lógica y corregir tu función, yo te propongo agregar 2 parámetros mas a la función:

- `$ascendencia`: Variable donde vamos a ir acumulando las claves de los padres
- `$resultado`: Variable pasada por referencia, donde vamos a ir guardando los hijos sin  hijos.

#### Ejemplo:

```
function getStringDescendientes($padres, $ascendencia = '', &$resultado = []) {
    foreach ($padres as $clave => $hijos) {
        // Agregamos el nombre del padre
        $herencia = $ascendencia . $clave . ';';

        // Si no tiene hijos lo agregamos al resultado
        if(empty($hijos)) {
            $resultado[] = $herencia;
        }
        // Si tiene hijos, los controlamos
        else {
            getStringDescendientes($hijos, $herencia, $resultado);
        }
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49b65580467d09a6317805eb098d5b9cd949fef3)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias Marcos, y por supuesto por la mejora y la explicación. Un saludo.